# Gradient computation

Tags: pytorch

I am beginner in data-science. I am trying to understand this PyTorch code for gradient computation using custom autograd function:

```
class MyReLU(torch.autograd.Function):

@staticmethod
def forward(ctx, x):

    ctx.save_for_backward(x)
    return x.clamp(min=0)

def backward(ctx, grad_output):

    x, = ctx.saved_tensors
    grad_x = grad_output.clone()
    grad_x[x < 0] = 0
    return grad_x
```

However, I don't understand this line : `grad_x[x < 0] = 0`. Can anyone explain this part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [example](https://github.com/jcjohnson/pytorch-examples/blob/master/README.md) you find is calculating the gradient for the [ReLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) function, whose gradient is
$$\text{ReLU}'(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{c l} 
     1 & \text{if } x>0\\
     0 & \text{if } x<0
\end{array}\right.$$

Therefore when `x<0`, you make the gradient 0 by `grad_x[x < 0] = 0`.